# presentViewController SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sigabrt, ios-universal-app

I am working on a universal app, when trying to select a photo from the devices library on

the iPad I get a SIGABRT error, but it works fine on the iPhone

```
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];  //the culprit, why?
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: How did you instantiate picker?

Comment: What OSs are both devices running?

Comment: Please note that you should see the complete error message in the console. The error clearly states what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the docs for `UIImagePickerViewController`:

> The table indicates that on iPad, if you specify a source type of `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` or `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`, you must present the image picker using a popover controller, as described in “Presenting and Dismissing the Popover” in `UIPopoverController` Class Reference. If you attempt to present an image picker modally (full-screen) for choosing among saved pictures and movies, the system raises an exception.
>
> On iPad, if you specify a source type of `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`, you can present the image picker modally (full-screen) or by using a popover. However, Apple recommends that you present the camera interface only full-screen.

You must use a `UIPopoverController` to present the image picker for the photo library on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // While showing UIImagePickerController in iPad, you must do it using UIPopoverController as follow 


        // Declare UIPopoverController and present your UIImagePickerController using it
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];

        popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```